# Get screnn shot in python3.7 by win32gui will cause memory leak

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, win32gui

Win10, python3.7
My code like this:

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api

screen_w = 2880
screen_h = 1800
x0 = int(screen_w * 0.866)
y0 = int(screen_h * 0.14)
ww = 220
hh = 70

def window_capture(filename): 
    hwnd = 0
    hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfcDC = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
    saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()
    saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, ww, hh)
    saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)
    saveDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (ww, hh), mfcDC, (x0, y0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    saveBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(saveDC, filename)
    #------------------
    win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
    saveDC.DeleteDC()
    mfcDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)
    #------------------

count = 0
while 1:
    window_capture('temp.png')
    count += 1
    if int(count/1000) == float(count/1000):
        print(count)
```

Firstly, I didn`t add DeleteObject and DeleteDC to release memory. The process will stop after about 10000 times window_capture.
But after I add them, I still can see the memory increase in task manager. Finally, after about 130000 times, the process stop again.

Does that mean I haven`t release all the memories? In my project, I need capture screen shot for a long time. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I don't know Python.

From Win32 perspective, you should not delete a GDI object while it is still selected into any DC (Device Context). You are doing precisely that here:

```
win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
```

The typical Win32 scenario is to save a handle of the object previously selected into DC (any of the `Select...()` functions return that), and re-select it into the DC when you are done with your own object.

Alternatively, you can use `SaveDC` / `RestoreDC` pair if you need to restore multiple objects.